# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') in CartItem

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, commerce.js

I am getting an error in while accessing the data present in the **cart** via **cartitem**. I am not so good at this. can someone help me in rectifying the error??

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia } from '@material-ui/core';

import useStyles from './styles';

const CartItem = ({ item }) => {
    const classes = useStyles
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardMedia image={item.media.source} alt={item.name} className={classes.media} />
            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                <Typography variant="h4">{item.name}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5">{item.line_total.formatted_with_symbol}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
                <div className={classes.buttons}>
                    <Button type="button" size="small">-</Button>
                    <Typography>{item.quantity}</Typography>
                    <Button type="button" size="small">+</Button>
                </div>
                <Button variant="contained" type="button" color="secondary">Remove</Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default CartItem
```

[These are a few errors poppoing in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15wpz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need more information to tell exactly why, but 'media' (or possibly item) seems to be undefined per the error.

You can add some saftey with this syntax:

```js
<CardMedia image={item?.media?.source} alt={item.name} className={classes.media} />
```

Notice the '?' above....more info on what that does [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: I tried it now, i am getting a new error saying like this.
Warning: Failed prop type: Material-UI: Either `children`, `image`, `src` or `component` prop must be specified.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the item into CartItem?  For example:  <CartItem item={someItemObject} />

Comment: yes I have passed item into cartItem. I have passes it as a parameter to the function. you can see it ryt after the import statements. The problem is i see all the data present in the cart but not the image of that respective product.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the anwser by @terpinmd, and your comment that of failed props. Use this

```
<CardMedia image={item?.media?.source || ““} alt={item.name} className={classes.media} />
```

This gives an empty string as a prop to image if item or item.media is undefined.